# Does every geometric progression contain a small remainder modulo a large prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

The exact question I am interested in is the following.

Fix a small $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ and an integer $q\ge 2$ (you may assume that $q$ is prime if it helps though I believe it shouldn't matter too much). For a large prime $P$ and an integer $a\in\mathbb Z$, define $G(a,P)=\{aq^m\mod P: m=0,1,2,\dots\}$ where the remainders are taken in the range $(-P/2, P/2)$ (i.e., with the minimal possible absolute value).

Is it true that for all primes $P$ outside of a set of density at most $\varepsilon$ (in any sense of the word "density" that is subadditive), $G(a,P)$ contains a remainder in the range $(-\varepsilon P,\varepsilon P)$ for every choice of $a\in \mathbb Z$?

However I'll be also interested in any nontrivial results in the same direction even if they fall somewhat short of a complete answer (be it affirmative or negative).

Comment: $a$ is chosen after $P$?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're almost asking if the cosets of multiplicative subgroups of the residues mod $p$ are equidistributed. This is known as long as the size of the subgroup is at most $p^{\delta}$ for some fixed $\delta$. Of course, there's still an issue of how q relates to the size of the induced multiplicative subgroup.

Comment: For almost all primes $P$, one will have that $G(a,P)$ is a coset of a subgroup of the multiplicative group mod P with size at least $P^{1/3}$. It seems an affirmative answer will follow from the result of Bourgain--Glibichuk--Konyagin appearing as Theorem 7 here, along with the Erdos-Turan inequality (Lemma 6): https://insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20019e3c_15.pdf

Comment: @MarkLewko  Yep, for almost all primes $P$ and $a\ne 0$ we shall have $|G(a,P)|\ge P^{\frac 12-\varepsilon}$ by an elementary counting argument, so it seems to answer the question in the affirmative. That's great. Let me see if I can understand the proof in Don's reference :-)

Comment: maybe the exact thing you are interested in is how fast $G(a, P)=\left\{a q^{m} \quad \bmod P: m=0,1,2, \ldots\right\}$ tend to equidistribution as $m$ grow?(fix q and let $p$ go to infinity and some uniformly discrepancy estimate on almost every prime)

Comment: @katago No, what I stated was exactly what would be sufficient to figure out what I wanted to figure out. I suspected that a stronger result might have been known (as it turned out to be the case) but I tried to request the minimum I would be happy with :-)

Comment: How difficult is to show that for almost all primes $P$, the subgroup generated by $q$ has size $(2\varepsilon)^{-1}\sqrt p\log p$ at least? The rest, I think, can be done with a very simple argument.

Comment: @Seva That may be not so easy but I'll try to push my trivial counting argument up a bit though to gain $\log p$ rather than a mere constant seems somewhat problematic. Meanwhile, if you can post your "very simple argument", we can also think if we can push it down to $\varepsilon\sqrt p$. The gap looks rather small, so, perhaps, it can be closed from one of the ends :-)

Comment: Ok, will try to post it tomorrow though, unfortunately, I cannot see a way to improve the estimates on my end.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what @Seva has in mind but what he claims should be true up to the factor of $(2\epsilon)^{-1}$ which might well also be true but I haven't checked carefully. The idea is, as our friend Don points out, that Erdos-Turan reduces the problem to showing an upperbound on an exponential sum of the form $\sum_{x} e( a x^k/ p)$ that beats the trivial estimate by more than a factor of $\log p$. Where $\{x^k : x \mod p\}$ is just another way of parameterizing our multiplicative subgroup.

Comment: Once the subgroup has an asymptotic size larger than  $p^{1/2}$ a non-trivial estimate certainly follows from Weil's bound. But, I *think* you should also be able to get a bound of sufficient strength by looking at moments. I also believe there is some work due to Shparlinski which goes below the exponent $1/2$ but doesn't get down to subgroups nearly as small as Bourgain-Glibichuk-Konyagin.

Comment: In any event, what you want is certainly true and provable.

Comment: Also regarding the ``counting argument" part of the approach, for large $c$, an unconditional lower estimate of the form $p^{1/2} \log^c p$ is known for almost every $p$. See: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.8.6190&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb F}$
$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$
(As reqested by the OP, and to address @Mark Lewko's comments, here is the argument showing that the statement is true for the primes satisfying a certain condition; the missing counterpart is to prove that almost all primes satisfy the condition in question.)

**Claim.** Suppose that $p$ is a prime, $H<\F_p^\times$, and $a\in\F_p^\times$. If $|H|>(2\eps)^{-1}\sqrt p\log p$, then the coset $aH$ has a non-empty intersection with the interval $I:=(-\eps p,\eps p)\subset\F_p$.

*Proof.* Let $H^\perp<\widehat{\F_p^\times}$; that is, $H^\perp$ is the subgroup of those multiplicative characters of $\F_p$ with $H$ in their kernel. Assuming for a contradiction that $aH\cap I=\varnothing$, we have
$$ \sum_{z\in\F_p^\times} \Big(\sum_{\chi\in H^\perp}\chi(a^{-1}z)\Big)\ \Big(\sum_{g\in I} \sum_{\psi\in\widehat{\F_p}} \psi(z-g)\Big) = 0 $$
where $\psi$ runs over all additive characters of $\F_p$. The contribution of the principal character $\psi=1$ is
$$ |I| \sum_{z\in\F_p^\times} \sum_{\chi\in H^\perp}\chi(a^{-1}z) = |I|p; $$
therefore, changing the order of summation and separating the terms with $\psi=1$, we get
$$ |I|p \le \sum_{\psi\ne 1} \Big| \sum_{g\in I} \psi(-g)\Big| \sum_{\chi\in H^\perp} \Big|\sum_{z\in\F_p^\times} \chi(a^{-1}z)\chi(z) \Big|. $$
The sum over $z$ is a Gauss sum; as such, it does not exceed $\sqrt p$ in the absolute value. This gives
$$ |I|p \le |H^\perp|\,\sqrt p \sum_{\psi\ne 1} \Big| \sum_{g\in I} \psi(-g)\Big|. $$
The outer sum in the right-hand side can be written explicitly as
$$ \sum_{u=1}^{p-1} \Big| \sum_{g=-\eps p}^{\eps p} e^{2\pi i ug/p}\Big|, $$
which easily yields the (well-known) upper bound $p\log p$ for the whole sum. As a result,
$$ |I|p \le |H^\perp| p^{3/2}\log p $$
and the assertion follows in view of $|H^\perp|=(p-1)/|H|$.

Comment: Thanks! It looks nice, indeed. Thanks to @MarkLewko too for pointing out how to improve the elementary counting argument (though "elementary" stops being "trivial" in that improvement) :-) Anyway, the question has been completely answered, so I'll push the "accept" button. However, if someone still wants to add something in comments or another answer, that will be always welcome.

Comment: I believe that it should be $\chi(a^{-1}z){\color{red}\psi(z)}$ in the rearranged sum and it looks like that if we use the Fejer kernel instead of the Dirichlet one, we can kill the $\log p$ factor. Am I right?

Comment: @fedja: For the first remark, the answer is "yes"; any other typos, to fix them all together? For the second remark - yes, as far as I can see, using Fejer's kernel saves the logarithm.